# Basic 3D Collision detection in XNA 4.0

Tags: collision-detection, xna-4.0

I have a problem with detecting collision between 2 models using BoundingSpheres in XNA 4.0. The code I'm using i very simple:

```
private bool IsCollision(Model model1, Matrix world1, Model model2, Matrix world2)
{
for (int meshIndex1 = 0; meshIndex1 < model1.Meshes.Count; meshIndex1++)
{
    BoundingSphere sphere1 = model1.Meshes[meshIndex1].BoundingSphere;
    sphere1 = sphere1.Transform(world1);

    for (int meshIndex2 = 0; meshIndex2 < model2.Meshes.Count; meshIndex2++)
    {
        BoundingSphere sphere2 = model2.Meshes[meshIndex2].BoundingSphere;
        sphere2 = sphere2.Transform(world2);

        if (sphere1.Intersects(sphere2))
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

The problem I'm getting is that when I call this method from the Update method, the program behaves as if this method always returns true value (which of course is not correct). The code for calling is very simple (although this is only the test code):

```
 if (IsCollision(model1, worldModel1, model2, worldModel2))
                {
                    Window.Title = "Intersects";
                }
```

What is causing this?

The way Im drawing the scene is to load the number of elements and their coordinates from a file like this (it is called from Update method):

```
OpenFileDialog Otvaranje = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keys.L))
            {
                this.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
                Otvaranje.ShowDialog();
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Otvaranje.FileName))
                    {
                        String linija;
                        while ((linija = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            red = linija.Split(',');                               
                            model = red[0];
                            x = red[1];
                            y = red[2];
                            z = red[3];
                            elementi.Add(Convert.ToInt32(model));
                            podatci.Add(new Vector3(Convert.ToSingle(x), Convert.ToSingle(y), Convert.ToSinglez)));                                                              
                            sfere.Add(new BoundingSphere(new Vector3(Convert.ToSingle(x), Convert.ToSingle(y), Convert.ToSingle(z)), 1f));                                                              

                        }
                    }
```

And then in the Update() method I had the following code (this was my first attempt):

```
if(sfere.Count != 0){
for(int i = 1; i<sfere.Count; i++)
{
 if(sfere[0].Intersects(sfere[i])) Window.Title = "Intersects"; 
}
}
```

This code never returned that collision is true because the bounding boxes are moving when the box moves, and I don't know why. The code that moves the box is this:

```
if (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed == Mouse.GetState().LeftButton)
                {
                    worldKutija = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0.01f, 0f, 0f)) * worldKutija;
                }
```

So if the model is set to be the box it is drawn into the worldKutija, and all other models are drawn into world matrix so they would not move with the box model. So why are their BoundingSpheres moving? After this started happening I tried the code I posted in the original question, and got the problems I was talking about

Comment: Do you reset the Window.Title to "Doesn't intersect" in every update, if there's no collision?

Comment: Yes I do (nothing happens), but the real problem is that the program detects collision when there is non. I have a scene with multiple objects, only one of them is moving, others are static. I want to check if the moving object is intersecting with any of those static objects

Comment: You could actually output some useful information to a log file perhaps. Like the current bounding spheres. This way, you can validate your method.
However, I would simply put a breakpoint inside the if (IsCollision(...)) block.

Comment: That didn't help because of the specific way I draw the objects on the scene. Their coordinates are not hard coded, I load them from a file (when the "L" key is pressed). And the moment I load the coordinates, the IsCollision returns the true value.

Comment: Why don't you use debugging, to see why are you getting an intersection? Just add a watch to your list of models and bounding spheres, and check out the coordinates. It would be much more productive then just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: I did that, the coordinates of 2 boundingSpheres are  Center {X:-0,3112391 Y:-0,09703492 Z:-0,1339329} (bs1)
Center {X:-0,3019615 Y:1,681244 Z:-0,01980543} (bs2)
So it is obvious they intersect, but the problem is that the models are not even near one another on the scene

Comment: So... that just proves that Roy T.'s answer (and mine) is correct.
Did you even try setting the center of the BoundingSpheres to the location of the corresponding models? If you did, please show us how you changed your methods.

Comment: I don't understand how would I change them, I set them when I load the file with this line `sfere.Add(new BoundingSphere(new Vector3(Convert.ToSingle(x), Convert.ToSingle(y), Convert.ToSingle(z)), 1f));` This way they should be in the same position as the models (and they are since I have a picking algorithm in the project that works fine - with the problem that I asked about in this question - http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/boundingspheres-move-when-they-should-not).

Comment: Yes, you are placing some bounding spheres from the file you load. But in the original algorithm you posted, you do not check the intersection of THOSE bounding spheres. In this code you're actually creating new spheres, and check those... but that's a problem, because you never set the center of these new spheres.

Comment: Aha, I thought that they would be created where the model is. I added this code into IsCollision method 
  `bs1.Center = sfere[0].Center;
   bs2.Center = sfere[1].Center;`
Now the application does not start with the intersect value true, but it never changes (even when models visually intersect). I think that is the same problem as the one I asked in the question I linked in my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to take the the bone transforms into account. Also It's not clear what is inside the World1 and World2 matrices, are you sure you move the boundingsphere's around and not just have them all be centered at (0,0)? Could you print out their origin's?

Anyway some code:

```
//Creates one bounding sphere for a model
BoundingSphere CreateBoundingSphereForModel(Model model, Matrix worldMatrix)
{
    Matrix[] boneTransforms = new Matrix[this.model.Bones.Count];
    this.model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(boneTransforms);

    BoundingSphere boundingSphere = new BoundingSphere();
    BoundingSphere meshSphere;         

    for (int i = 0; i < model.Meshes.Count; i++)
    {                
        meshSphere = model.Meshes[i].BoundingSphere.Transform(boneTransforms[i]);                
        boundingSphere = BoundingSphere.CreateMerged(boundingSphere, meshSphere);
    }
    return boundingSphere.Transform(worldMatrix);       
}

//Check intersection between two models
bool IsCollision(Model model1, Matrix world1, Model model2, Matrix world2)
{
    BoundingSphere bs1 = CreateBoundingSphereForModel(model1, world1);
    BoundingSphere bs2 = CreateBoundingSphereForModel(model2, world2);

    if(bs1.Intersects(bs2))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Note that it would be better to create a new class that holds the model, the matrix and caches the bounding spheres to improve performance.

Edit: it seems from the comments above that the problem is that the matrices are wrong, just putting both sphere's at (0,0,0). So instead to solve that use below code to create a proper world matrix:

```
Matrix world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(object1Position) * Matrix.CreateScale(object1Scale); 
// We don't need rotation since it doesn't matter how the sphere is rotatated ;)
```

Here object1Position is a Vector3 that you probably also use the draw the model at a certain position in the world.

Comment: Upvoted. This answer contains the solution, so I won't update mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your BoundingSpheres might not be in the proper positions.

```
private bool IsCollision(Model model1, Matrix world1, Model model2, Matrix world2) 
{ 
for (int meshIndex1 = 0; meshIndex1 < model1.Meshes.Count; meshIndex1++) 
{ 
BoundingSphere sphere1 = model1.Meshes[meshIndex1].BoundingSphere; 
sphere1 = sphere1.Transform(world1);
//EDIT:
sphere1.Center += obj1.Position;
//

for (int meshIndex2 = 0; meshIndex2 < model2.Meshes.Count; meshIndex2++) 
{ 
    BoundingSphere sphere2 = model2.Meshes[meshIndex2].BoundingSphere; 
    sphere2 = sphere2.Transform(world2); 
    //EDIT:
    sphere2.Center += obj2.Position;
    //

    if (sphere1.Intersects(sphere2)) 
        return true; 
} 
} 
return false;
```

Implying that obj1 and obj2 are the world objects, and their corresponding models are model1 and model2.
I have no idea what you have in those world1 and world2 matrices though... maybe you could show us some more code.

Comment: The world1 contains only one model (simple box), and world2 contains "workstations". Both world1 and world 2 are the same:
`private Matrix world1 = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
 private Matrix world2 = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));` 
This is a college project I'm doing and the goal is to load the configuration of an assembly line and then check if the box passes in front of a certain workstation. I solved the loading part, and for this second one I added the "laser" model, and if the box intersects with the laser, it should stop.

Comment: Yeah, then your BoundingSpheres are definitely in the wrong place. Set their Center properties to the objects' position.

Comment: What do you mean by world object? Sorry, I'm a beginner, so please be patient with me.

Comment: I mean the objects that are represented by the models. Like a car, a ball or something like that. If the models don't belong to such an object, just use the center of the model as the center of the BoundingSphere.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing already. The file I load the configuration from contains the coordinates to which I want the program to draw the models. I use 2 lists, one List<Vector3> that holds the positions to which the models are drawn, and I added another List<BoundingSphere> to hold the bounding spheres (in the same coordinates). So for each line in the file, one model is drawn to the scene, and one BoundingSphere is added. I tried to loop trough the second list, but it seems that the BoundingSpheres move with the box model, although they are defined using different world matrices

Comment: Then why are you creating new BoundingSpheres in your loop:

BoundingSphere sphere2 = model2.Meshes[meshIndex2].BoundingSphere;

Comment: Your matrices need to be: Matrix world1 = Matrix.CreateTranslation(model1Position)*Matrix.CreateScale(scale1); else both boundingspheres are at (0,0,0) instead of at the place of where the models are drawn and so always intersect. The solution to just change the center is ok too but you can do it with the matrices in one go (else it's useless to pass the matrices)

Comment: @Marton. I edited my question so if you could take a look, it might clear some things up.